# Where does the name 'LSTM' come from?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, terminology

Long short-term memory is a recurrent neural network architecture introduced in the paper [Long short-term memory](http://deeplearning.cs.cmu.edu/pdfs/Hochreiter97_lstm.pdf).

Can you please tell me where the name comes from?

("Memory", as the network can store information because of the recurrence - but where does the "Long short-term" come from?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Sepp Hochreiter's original paper on the LSTM](http://goo.gl/JSaqb4)   where he introduces the algorithm and method to the scientific community, he explains that the long term memory refers to the learned weights and the short term memory refers to the gated cell state values that change with each step through time *t*.

**edit:** quote from paper *"Recurrent networks can in principle use their feedback connections to store representations of recent input events in the form of activations ("short-term memory", as opposed to "long-term memory embodied by slowly changing weights)*"